# Is there a way to create Wright Maps (item-person maps) in R using individual person labels in the visualization?

Tags: r, plot

In the past I have used WinSteps for the creation of item-person maps for IRT projects. I found the option to represent individual persons with a variable label particularly useful. Below is an example of what I mean:

[image: an example item-person map]

Here the items (44b,44a,42b,45b,45c) and persons (TD, RSK, SD) are represented by character labels at their respective Beta and Theta levels on the trait scale. In this example, the person labels represent diagnostic groups. This is helpful for visualizing which items are measuring which groups in the person distribution.

Is there any way to create this type of map in R?

So far I have only been able to find resources for producing person histograms and density plots using the WrightMap function shown below

[image: example R WrightMap output with person histogram]

Is there a way to coerce the personHist argument into using labels rather than bars to represent the distribution of person theta values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. The `wrightMap` method from the **WrightMap** package offers customizable item- and person-side plots. However, you'll need some work to do to get a nice looking plot.

If we study the implementation of the method, we find that the person-side plot is generated via a call to

```
do.call(person.side, c(person.params, dots))
```

whereas `person.side` is a plotting function (by default that is `personHist` -- for greater detail cf. to the manual page for `personHist`) and the `person.params` objects is a list of arguments which is set as

```
person.params <- list(thetas = thetas, yRange = yRange, close.on.close = FALSE,
                      oma = c(0, 0, 0, 0), axis.logits = "", show.axis.logits = FALSE)
```

The `thetas` object from this list is the same as the input object. Noteably, the object keeps its names during the computations. We can use that to construct out person side plot. Using example data adapted from the packages manual

```
set.seed(20231020)
library(WrightMap)
uni.proficiency <- rnorm(10, mean =  -0.5, sd = 1)
uni.proficiency <- setNames(uni.proficiency, paste0("id", sprintf("%03i", 1:length(uni.proficiency))))
difficulties  <- sort( rnorm( 20))
```

We can e.g. define

```
my_person.side <- function(thetas, yRange, oma, ...) {
  
  r <- hist(thetas, breaks = "FD", plot = FALSE)
  y <- cut(thetas, breaks = r$breaks, labels = r$mids)
  x <- numeric(length = length(y))
  text <- names(thetas)
  
  for(bb in levels(y)) {# bb <- levels(y)[1]
    x[y == bb] <- 0:(-c(table(y)[bb]) + 1)
  }
  
  par(oma = oma)
  plot(x, y, type = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "", 
       ylim = yRange, xlim = c(min(x) - 0.5, 0), cex.lab = 0.8, 
       font.lab = 3)
  
  text(x = x, y = as.numeric(as.character(y)), labels = text, cex = .7)
}
```

And a call to

```
wrightMap(uni.proficiency, difficulties, person.side = my_person.side)
```

gives

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is extremely helpful and I was able to replicate the format using my data. However, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to map the specific ID points onto persons in my data in a way that is intuitive in the output chart. It seems that the "id" name is applied in whatever order the thetas appear in the data. What part of the code might I need to alter to have a specific grouping variable name applied. A simple example would be assigning M/F to the data points to see where male/female persons are on the theta scale.

Comment: I was able to figure it out - adding the specific variable name in the text argument of the my_person.side function did the trick: text(x = x, y = as.numeric(as.character(y)), labels = DATA$VARIABLE, cex = .7)

Thanks again!